# How to extract vuejs data value

Tags: arrays, vue.js, dictionary

```
data(){
  return {
      filters: [
        { key: 'a', value: '12' },
        { key: 'b', value: '34' },
        { key: 'c', value: '56' },
        { key: 'd', value: '78' },
        { key: 'e', value: '90' },
      ], 
  }
}
```

How to extract '34' ?

Can we achieve that like this ?

```
console.log(this.filters.key)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method.

```
this.filters.find(({ value }) => value === '34').value;
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      filters: [
        { key: 'a', value: '12' },
        { key: 'b', value: '34' },
        { key: 'c', value: '56' },
        { key: 'd', value: '78' },
        { key: 'e', value: '90' },
      ], 
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getValue() {
        return this.filters.find(({ value }) => value === '34').value;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ getValue }}</p>
</div>
```